# Passing sparkSession Between Scala Spark and PySpark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

My requirement is to call a "Spark Scala" function from an existing PySpark program.
What is the best way to pass sparkSession created in PySpark program to Scala function.
I pass my scala jar to Pyspark as follows.

```
spark-submit --jars ScalaExample-0.1.jar pyspark_call_scala_example.py iris.data
```

## Scalacode

```
def getDf(spark: SparkSession, query:String, df: DataFrame, log: Logger): DataFrame = {

import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.sql(query)

df

}
```

## Pysparkcode

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

query = sys.argv[1]

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("PySpark using Scala example") \
.getOrCreate()

log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j 

log = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__) 

query_df = DataFrame(sc._jvm.com.crowdstrike.dsci.sparkjobs.PythonHelper.getDf(???, query, ???), sqlContext)
```

## Question

How to pass sparksession and logger to getDf ?

https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/spark-hot-potato-passing-dataframes-between-scala-spark-and-pyspark/

Comment: Hi and welcome. You can include code in formatted code blocks by using 3 back ticks. This will make more readable and more likely to get an answer. here's more info https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Edits are done and reviewed and approved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To pass SparkSession from Python to Scala, use `spark._jsparkSession`.